# Security constraints if complete Source Code can be extracted from APK/IPA

Tags: android, apk, ipa

if we can get complete source code from apk files , does that mean all the apps for which we get apk files we can extract source code , isn’t it a security issue?

Comment: I think this question would be better asked (and perhaps already answered?) over on [security.se] or [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: `proguard` play the game here!!, one of the major benefit of implementing `proguard` is to Obfuscate of the code while building a release APK (it replaces the classes/fun name with some short names which is really difficult to read if you extract the source code).